# Pass multiple value in where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, multiple-columns, where-clause

```
SELECT
     "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."AGE",
     "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."RELATION",
     "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."NAME",
     "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."ENTRY_DATE",
     "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."CLAIM_AMT",
     CASE
     WHEN "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."Gender" = 'F'
     THEN 'FEMALE'
     ELSE 'MALE'
     END AS GENDER,
     "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."STATUS",
     "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."APPROVED_AMT"
FROM
     "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"
WHERE "dbo"."ClaimDataFormat"."AGE" = CASE 
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '0-10' 
                               THEN 0 
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '0-10'
                               THEN 1
                     WHEN ${TimeGran} = '0-10'
                               THEN 2
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '0-10'
                               THEN 3
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '0-10'
                               THEN 4
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '0-10'
                               THEN 5  
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '0-10'
                               THEN 6
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '0-10'
                               THEN 7
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '0-10'
                               THEN 8
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '0-10'
                               THEN 9
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '0-10'
                               THEN 10
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '11-20'
                               THEN 11 
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '11-20'
                               THEN 12
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '11-20'
                               THEN 13
                     WHEN ${TimeGran} = '11-20'
                               THEN 14
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '11-20'
                               THEN 15
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '11-20'
                               THEN 16
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '11-20'
                               THEN 17  
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '11-20'
                               THEN 18
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '11-20'
                               THEN 19
                          WHEN ${TimeGran} = '11-20'
                               THEN 20

                          ELSE 21
                     END
```

if the age band is 0-10 the all values between 0 and 10 must be reflected

Comment: what exactly are u asking about?

Comment: is it giving any error ?

Comment: Please just dont show how you tried also show what you want to achieve. Add some sample data with expected output that would help us understand  what you want.

Comment: no my code is not giving me any error but at the same time im not getting my desire result also......... Actually i want when i select 0-10 my result set should be of all the ages between 0 to 10.... have i made myself clear now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
SELECT dbo.ClaimDataFormat.AGE,
       dbo.ClaimDataFormat.RELATION,
       dbo.ClaimDataFormat.NAME,
       dbo.ClaimDataFormat.ENTRY_DATE,
       dbo.ClaimDataFormat.CLAIM_AMT,
       CASE
         WHEN dbo.ClaimDataFormat.Gender = 'F' THEN 'FEMALE'
         ELSE 'MALE'
       END AS GENDER,
       dbo.ClaimDataFormat.STATUS,
       dbo.ClaimDataFormat.APPROVED_AMT
FROM   dbo.ClaimDataFormat
WHERE  ( dbo.ClaimDataFormat.AGE BETWEEN 0 AND 10
         AND TimeGran = '0-10' )
        OR ( dbo.ClaimDataFormat.AGE BETWEEN 11 AND 20
             AND TimeGran = '11-20' )
        OR ( dbo.ClaimDataFormat.AGE = 21
             AND TimeGran NOT IN ( '0-10', '11-20' ) )
```

Comment: thanks for reply... bt still there is some problem..... the TimeGran is an i/p variable....in ur code if i select the option 0-10 it is giving me the result of 21.. can u recheck again......

Comment: thanks Mr NoDisplayName ........ i added some of my brain(a bit) and i got the o/p ........

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like that you need something like this:

```
WHERE 
  AGE >= convert(int, left(@timeGrain, charindex ('-', @timeGrain) - 1)) and
  AGE <= convert(int, substring(@timeGrain, charindex ('-', @timeGrain) + 1, 9999))
```

This will split the timegrain from - and use those as upper / lower limit. For the else part, you probably need to have some kind of OR -clause, but can't write it since I have no idea what your possible value is in that case.